# Finding characters within a string in C

Tags: c, string, character

I'm writing an algorithm in C with netbeans to find asterisks in a string.

```
int main() {
    int M=0, i, j;
    scanf("%i",&M);
    int pos[M];
    char c[M];
    scanf("%s", c);

    i=0;
    j=1;

    while(c[i] != '\0'){
        if(c[i]=='*'){
            pos[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("Asterisks in positions: \n\n");

    for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
        printf("%i", pos[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work, it prints a lot of numbers even if M is a small number.

Comment: You did not ask a question.  StackOverflow is a place to get questions answered.

Comment: What input are you giving your program?  What output are you getting?  What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information regarding how many asterisks you found is stored in the counter j.  This variable gets reset in the for loop:

```
for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
```

Furthermore, this for loop goes all the way up to i, which is the length of the your input string.  Try reworking your loop as follows:

```
for(i=1; i<j; i++){    
    printf("%i", pos[i]);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be you never take into account the number of characters found. You print the whole vector, using `i` instead of `j` to iterate. It's `j` that holds the number of matches.

Also, try using [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/), from cstring :)

Get the first position, then search again from the next character until null is returned.

Comment: Or `strcspn()` which returns a count of the characters skipped.

Answer (score 0):

After your `while` loop completes, `j` holds the total number of positions recorded, so you should be printing from `pos[1]` to `pos[j]`. Your current loop prints from `pos[1]` to `pos[i]`. Just invert the variables in your final loop:

```
for(i=1; i<=j; i++){
    printf("%i", pos[i]);
}
```